# Countable anti-chain in an Aronszajn tree

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

The problem I'm facing is to show there exists a countable anti-chain in an Aronszajn tree $T$. I thought of something, and I wanted to ask you if my proof is correct.

So, the idea is to proceed inductively and in each finite step take a node of the tree which is on some level above the end of every possible branch which goes through any of the previous nodes taken. Such a node has to exist since all the branches are at most countable, so they are bounded in $\omega_1$.

Technically I though we could take $x_0$ to be any node on the $0$-th level and $x_n$ to be some node from a level above $\gamma_{x_{n-1}}>\textrm{length of the longest branch going through any of }x_i\ i<n$. There is no guarantee level $\gamma_{x_{n-1}}$ is non-empty, but some of the levels above surely are, since height of the tree is $\omega_1$.

In each step I make at most countably many steps, so $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a countable anti-chain.

I feel something's not right. What do you think?

Comment: Won't it be enough, and perhaps easier, to prove there are countably many nodes in every "sufficiently high" (could be $1$ and could be $\omega$, or could be higher, depending on your tree) level, then those will be antichains? (You can give an easy non-constructive proof, too, if $T$ is a tree of height $\omega_1$ and every level is finite, then $T$ contains a branch. This is a particular case of a lemma by Kurepa, I believe, that if $T$ has height $\lambda^+$ with every level strictly less than $\lambda$, then $T$ has a cofinal branch; it might be necessary for $\lambda$ to be regular...)

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about this too, but the above seemed more natural to me (if I could use the term "natural" here).

Comment: Oh man, you're right, it stems from the Kurepa theorem too! Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer to this, by the way.